# Display JSONStringer result in TextView

Tags: java, android, json, string

Hello I'm new to webservices and json so I ask your help how to display JSONStringer result in a textView.

**This is the code I'm working on:**

```
           // Build JSON string
           JSONStringer TestApp = new JSONStringer().object().key("id")
                        .value("1").key("name").value("manish").key("email")
                        .value("androidhub4you@gmail.com").key("country")
                        .value("india").endObject();
           String entity = new StringEntity(TestApp.toString());
           String var = entity.toString();
```

**To display:**

```
                TextView tv  = (TextView) findViewById (R.id.tvText);
        tv.setText(var);
```

The problem is it's just prints

```
   org.apache.http.entity StringEntity....
```

. I'd greatly appreciate your help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

```
String var = entity.toString();
```

with

```
String var = EntityUtils.toString(entity)
```

`StringEntity.toString()` returns the address of the object

Comment: Thanks but how about display only the data not included the {} braces?

Comment: @neknekmouh why would you want to display it in a textview?

Comment: @neknekmouh you have to parse your json. Can you bit more specific about what you need? T

Comment: I'll start another thread.. Thanks. this is the link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16997245/android-display-json-object-to-listview